# SQL to convert log to on/off/mixed by date table For analysis

Tags: sql, powerbi

I want to do some analysis based on whether an item is on/off by several other metrics I'll be pulling in PowerBI, but to do so I need to have by-date detail where I have activity logs.
I have a table logging when items have been restricted/unrestricted like

| ID | Restricted | DateUpdated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 0 | 2022-09-27 16:52:31.960 |
| 5678 | 0 | 2022-09-27 16:52:31.683 |
| 5678 | 1 | 2022-09-26 11:52:09.430 |
| 5678 | 0 | 2022-09-24 12:50:18.150 |
| 5678 | 1 | 2022-09-22 11:59:08.897 |
| 1234 | 1 | 2022-09-21 10:42:12.883 |

currently with ~2500 rows for 2022.
For analysis of the effects of these restrictions, I need to know what the status of each item was by date such as

| ID | Restricted | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5678 | 0 | 2022-09-28 |
| 5678 | 1 | 2022-09-27 |
| 5678 | 1 | 2022-09-26 |
| 5678 | 0 | 2022-09-25 |
| 5678 | 1 | 2022-09-24 |
| 5678 | 1 | 2022-09-23 |
| 5678 | 1 | 2022-09-22 |

with items restricted before noon being restricted for that day and after noon restricted for the following day. If this adds significant complication, a on/off/mixed table would provide significant value.

I have SQL showing what is currently restricted

```
select a.ID, Restricted, a.DateUpdated from [RestrictionLogs] a
left join (select an.ID, max(an.DateUpdated) as lastupdate from [RestrictionLogs] an group by ID) c on a.ID=c.ID
and a.DateUpdated=c.lastupdate
order by a.DateUpdated desc
```

but I have not been able to figure out how to assign historical on/off values at scale without manually filling in 1's and 0's for anything not in the current status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a Power Query solution:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("fc+xDcMwDETRVQTWNsE7SRTFVQTvv4ZjI4VTOAW7h4/jWgLWJpvY52jkbnPnKPDszAqdbnJsS7qP+MM86pPhybwAF7Oprb7XWgGzWyIU3V5rvGszLTTmuNn3hR+GAsvGBDWubccJ", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ID = _t, Restricted = _t, DateUpdated = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Restricted", Int64.Type}, {"DateUpdated", type datetime}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"DateUpdated", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "StartDate", each [DateUpdated] +#duration(0,12,0,0)),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"StartDate", type date}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type1", {"ID"}, #"Changed Type1", {"ID"}, "Rows", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Custom", each let mydate = [StartDate] in Table.SelectRows([Rows], each [StartDate] > mydate)),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom.1", each Table.First([Custom])),
    #"Expanded Custom.1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Custom.1", {"StartDate"}, {"EndDateIntermediate"}),
    #"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Custom.1", "EndDate", each if [EndDateIntermediate] = null then Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) else [EndDateIntermediate]),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom4", "Date", each {Number.From([StartDate])..Number.From([EndDate] -#duration(1,0,0,0) )}),
    #"Expanded dates" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom3", "Date"),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded dates",{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type2",{"Rows", "Custom", "EndDateIntermediate"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

It's a little ugly, but here is a summary of the steps:

1. Add a 12 hour offset to account for the "noon criteria". Call this "StartDate"
2. Merge (join) the table with itself on id. take only the next start date from the merged data. Call this "EndDateIntermediate"
3. If some ID does not have an end date, use the current date. Call this "EndDate"
4. Create a list of dates from "StartDate" to "EndDate" for each row

And here is the result in Power BI:

[image: result]

Comment: After adding a filter to remove nulls introduced into my source, this appears to solve the problem, Thanks!